# XPATH Preserving Tag

Tags: xml, xpath, tags

Hi i have an xml like this one:

```
<root>
    <parent1>
        <leaf1>value1</leaf1>
        <leaf2>value1</leaf2>
        <leaf3>value1</leaf3>
        <leaf4>value1</leaf4>
    </parent1>
    <parent2>
        <leaf1>value1</leaf1>
        <leaf2>value1</leaf2>
        <leaf3>value1</leaf3>
        <leaf4>value1</leaf4>
        ...
        <leafN>value1</leafN>
    </parent2>
</root>
```

i need to extract this as output:

```
<leaf1>value1</leaf1>
<leaf2>value1</leaf2>
<leaf3>value1</leaf3>
<leaf4>value1</leaf4>
...
<leafN>value1</leafN>
```

how can i write and xpath query giving me the possibility to skip some nodes... for example: leaf1 and leaf3?

Answer (score 1):

If the XML is as simple as in the question, to extract all `root`'s grandchildren you can use:

```
/*/*/*
```

And to exclude `leaf1` and `leaf3` you can use something like:

```
/*/*/*[not(self::leaf1) and not(self::leaf3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all leaf node not depending on the structure of tree excluding some nodes, use the xpath:

```
//*[count(*)=0 and not(self::leaf1) and not(self::leaf3)]
```